# Ionic + PrepopulatedDB

Tags: database, sqlite, ionic-framework, device

I've been trying to get my cordova app working on a device with a prefilled database (using SQLite and DbCopy) and I've encountered a problem following a tutorial. When using **ionic run android**, to run the application on a device, the first time it works perfect, but when I run it for the second time db is null and it won't work again until I remove the Database and start all over again.

```
var db = null;

angular.module("alterApp", ["ionic", "ngCordova"])
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar){
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("prefilledDB.db", function() {
            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "prefilledDB.db"  });
        }, function(error) {
            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "prefilledDB.db" });
        });
    });
})
```

Any thoughts ? If there is another way to use a prefilled database with Ionic then I could use it too.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: Are you closing your database properly? Maybe it's being corrupted.

Comment: Please check this article http://ioniccode.blogspot.com/2015/12/deploy-ionic-framework-app-with-pre.html

Comment: I've already tried that and it seems is not working with current cordova version or stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem but finally I resorted to PouchDB.

You can use PouchDB [http://pouchdb.com/] and that might solve your issues.

Comment: I'll give it a try whenever i can. Thanks.

Comment: Pouchdb and couchdb live reload feature will also allow you to change prefilled data when ever you require, Just update data to couchdb server and it will be replicated to pouchdb on client side

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with SQLite db as follows:

I put the database_name.db in the *www* folder and then I wrote the code in the controller.
    var dbName = "database_name.db";
    var db = null;

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";

if (window.sqlitePlugin) { //device
    //Copy and open the database
    window.plugins.sqlDB.copy(dbName, 0, function () {
        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: dbName, location: 1}, function (db)` {
            db.executeSql(query,[],function(result){
                  console.log(result.rows.length);
            },function(err){
                  console.log("Error:" + err.message);
            });
        }, function (err) {
             console.log('Error opening the database: ' + err.message);
        });
}, function (error) {
      console.error("Error copying the database: " + error.message);
      db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: dbName, location: 1}, function (db) {
db.executeSql(query,[],function(result){
      console.log(result.rows.length);
},function(err){
     console.log("Error:" + err.message);
);
}, function (err) {
    console.log('Error opening the database: ' + err.message);
});
});
} else{ //browser
db = window.openDatabase(dbName, 1, dbName, -1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to try it. Been trying to figure out a way to package my Cordova app with a pre-loaded DB.

Question, can you delete the copy of the db stored in the "www" folder? That will just be wasted space after the first load right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know because I have not tried it. But if you tell so I will try to understand if it is possible and if there is a solution. If i will find it, I will tell you. I want to tell you that I modified the code putting code about copy in app.js and the other part (opening and selection) in the controller

Answer (score 0):

I have had good success with Ionic apps and SQL lite using a "schema-version" record where I increment a number every time I modify the schema.  Then, I have a database migration/sql file that corresponds to the schema version number.  This pattern works pretty well for enterprise app development where the data schema changes over time.

This [app](https://github.com/danbucholtz/ionic2-weight-tracker/blob/master/app/app.ts) provides a quality example of the pattern.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a plugin cordova-sqlite-ext for my project and it works fine.
Here is some tips and notes from documentation:

**Pre-populated database(s)**

Put the database file in the www directory and open the database like (both database location and createFromLocation items are required):

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db", location: 'default', createFromLocation: 1});

IMPORTANT NOTES:

Put the pre-populated database file in the www subdirectory. (This should work well the Cordova CLI.)
The pre-populated database file name must match exactly the file name given in openDatabase. This plugin does not use an automatic extension.
The pre-populated database file is ignored if the database file with the same name already exists in your database file location.
TIP: If you don't see the data from the pre-populated database file, completely remove your app and try it again!

Alternative: You can also use an-rahulpandey / cordova-plugin-dbcopy to install a pre-populated database

*source: https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext*